# Examples and definition of cocompact objects

Tags: category-theory

An object $X$ of a locally small category $C$ that admits filtered colimits is called [compact](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object) if 
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(X,-)
$$
preserves filtered colimits.

Let $C$ be a locally small category that admits filtered limits. Let's define an object $X$ of $C$ to be *cocompact* if 
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(-,X)
$$
sends cofiltered limits to filtered colimits in $Sets$.

> I never heard of this definition before. Is it reasonable? If yes, what are typical examples of cocompact objects in $Sets$, $Top$, etc?

Comment: You mean a cofiltered limit.

Comment: Cocompactness is not as useful as compactness because many categories of interest are $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ for some $\mathcal{A}$, but not so many are $\mathbf{Pro}(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Do you know of any examples or non-examples in $Sets$ or $Top$?

Comment: I believe the only cocompact objects in $\mathbf{Set}$ are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to call the quoted categorical concept of compactness *strong compactness*, since it is stronger than the usual notion of compactness for topological spaces.

We can express the definition of *strong cocompactness* of an object $D$ as the requirement that any morphism $\lim_{i \in I}C_i \to D$, with $I$ a cofiltered diagram, should factor through one of the limit projections $\pi_j: \lim_{i \in I}C_i \to C_j$. We see from this reformulation that if any subset/subspace of a set/space $X$ fails to be strongly cocompact, we can therefore deduce that $X$ is not strongly compact either; we use this to help us in our search.

In $\mathbf{Set}$, consider $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2$ as a cofiltered limit of copies of finite products of the two-element set, $2$. Given any set $X$ with two or more distinct elements, pick two such elements and call them $0$ and $1$; label the elements of $2$ the same way. Then we have a function $f: \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2 \to X$ sending a sequence to $0$ if the sequence contains a $1$ *and* the first $1$ in the sequence is followed by a $0$; and to $1$ otherwise. By construction, this cannot factor through the projection from $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2$ to any finite product. Clearly any morphism from a cofiltered limit to the one-element set $1$ factors through one (indeed any) of its projection maps. However, contrary to what Zhen Lin said in the comments, $0$ is not strongly cocompact in $\mathbf{Set}$, since if we consider the codirected limit of subsets $[n,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, whose intersection is empty, we see that this is not preserved by $\mathrm{Hom}(-,\emptyset)$.

By passing across the forgetful-indiscrete adjunction $(U \dashv I)$ between $\mathbf{Top}$ and $\mathbf{Set}$, we can use the same argument as above to deduce that any *indiscrete* space with more than 2 points, or indeed any non-$T_0$ space, cannot be strongly cocompact in $\mathbf{Top}$. If the subspace of $X$ on the points $0$ and $1$ is homeomorphic to the Sierpinski space, such that $0$ is open, the argument still works, since the set $f^{-1}(0)$ of sequences described above is the union of opens $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \{0\}_i \times \{1\}_n \times \{0\}_{n+1} \times \prod_{i=n+2}^{\infty} 2$$
in $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2$. This union is disjoint and there can be arbitrarily many non-trivial projection indices, so $f$ cannot factor through any of the projections to finite products of $2$.

The argument fails more generally, though, since $f$ cannot be continuous for any choice of points of $X$ when $X$ is Hausdorff, say, since the subspace consisting of the points $\{0,1\}$ is necessarily discrete in that case, and $f^{-1}(1)$ is not open in $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2$.

Instead, consider
$$Y_0 := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \mid x+y \geq 0\},$$
topologized with basic open sets $U_{a,b} := \{(x,y) \mid x \geq a, \, y \geq b\}$. Then we have a directed collection of subspaces,
$$Y_n := \{(x,y) \in Y_0 \mid 2^n \text{ divides } x+y \};$$
these subspaces are all connected, but their intersection is the subspace
$$Y_{\infty} := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \mid x+y = 0\},$$
homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology. Suppose $X$ has a pair of points $\{0,1\}$ such that the subspace on these points is discrete. Then we have a continuous map $Y_{\infty} \to X$ sending $(x,y)$ to $0$ if $y \geq x$ and to $1$ otherwise. This function cannot factor through any of the $Y_n$, though, since the inverse images of $0$ and $1$ would have to non-trivially disconnect $Y_n$, which is impossible.

**In summary: Since we have exhausted the possibilities for two-point subspaces, and the argument for the emptyset carries across, we have shown that in $\mathbf{Top}$, just as in $\mathbf{Set}$, the singleton space is the only strongly cocompact space.**

---

As a final observation, if $R$ is a functor having a left adjoint $L$ which preserves cofiltered limits (if $L$ has a further left adjoint, for example) then $R$ preserves strongly cocompact objects. Indeed, letting $X$ be strongly cocompact and $I$ be a cofiltered indexing diagram, we have:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\lim_{i \in I}Y_i,R(X)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(L(\lim_{i \in I}Y_i),X) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\lim_{i \in I}L(Y_i),X)$$
$$\cong \mathrm{colim}_{i \in I}\mathrm{Hom}(L(Y_i),X) \cong \mathrm{colim}_{i \in I}\mathrm{Hom}(Y_i,R(X)),$$
so even without the explicit calculations in $\mathbf{Top}$, we could have deduced that the terminal space $1$ is strongly cocompact, since it is the image of the one-element set under the indiscrete functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Top}$ mentioned earlier.